# Using exec while redirecting the output to a text file seems to lock said file

Tags: php, apache

On a WAMP configuration, I am executing a shell command with `exec` and redirecting the output with `>> log.txt`. The commando is called many times in the script. The first time, the file is created, and the first output is written on it, but it seems the file stream is not closed (I can't delete the file, and Windows tells me that the file is opened by somebody else), and as such the script try to continue loading but do nothing else, and is still try after the 5 minutes limit I set for this script.

Am I doing something wrong? If yes why? Otherwise where does the problem lies?

**EDIT:** I've confirmed that by commenting the code line that it is the source of my problem. Furthermore, although I interrupted the script, the file remained locked to any change (edit/move/delete).

**EDIT 2:** Using `pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"))` instead, as suggested in [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329) doesn't seems to bring anything, regardless If I use `>> log.txt` or not.

**EDIT 3:** After a forced unwanted reboot of the server, the issue isn't there anymore.

I've talked with some colleague which encountered a similar problem with their application, and they said that rebooting their server always "solved" the problem. But I don't call that a solution if the problem comes again sooner or later. So it seems that the "silent update" scenario is the more possible.

In the meantime the server will be migrated to a machine with a newer OS (Windows 2008 Server). I'll wait and see if the problem comes again, but if possible I would like to takes measures so I don't have to deal with it in the future.

Comment: why would you log the output of diffrent processes in the same file? Process that writes to a file always aquire exclusive lock on the file

Comment: @Darhazer: Well it worked at one time, and I don't have a clue what I changed to not make it work... Anyway, logging the output in different files (using a timestamp) doesn't bring anything, it still blocks at the first attempts. I know, I've tried.

Comment: It's WAMP, for all you know a stealth update came along and altered functionality.  As far as I know this sort of non-locking behavior shouldn't really work at all so it's reasonable to interpret this as a security fix.

Comment: What happens if you EXEC the command twice - in the same exec() or in 2 exec()s one after the other?

Comment: @BurninLeo, it didn't get past the first one.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you exec($cmd, $output, $result) ? this will return the output in the $output variable. you can then do a file_put_contents($file, implode("\r\n", $output), FILE_APPEND)

this will let you append the output of the command right into the log file in pure php way